# Model stops improving validation accuracy at 46-49% it is seemingly overfitting

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, resnet

I am working on this dataset:

**https://www.kaggle.com/dionyshsmiaris/xrays** which includes xrays of class:

1. 0="normal"
2. 1="pneumonia_cause_viral_infection"
3. 2="pneumonia_cause_bacteria"

I am using a custom resnet of **depth=50**(although I tried 20 ,34 ,101) with the same results.

**That is my import of data:**

```
train_dir = "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Xraydataset/train_images/"
test_dir =  "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Xraydataset/test_images/"
def get_data(folder):
  X = []
  y = []
  for image_filename in tqdm(os.listdir(folder)):
    img_file = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(folder + '/' + image_filename,color_mode="grayscale")
    if img_file is not None:
      img_file=img_file.resize((224,224),1) 
      img_arr = np.asarray(img_file)
      X.append(img_arr)
  label=pd.read_csv('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Xraydataset/labels_train.csv',usecols = ['class_id'])
  X = np.asarray(X)
  y = np.asarray(label)

  return X,y
X_train, y_train = get_data(train_dir)
X_test, y_test= get_data(test_dir)
```

**Preprocessing,normalization,to categorical :**

```
#print (X_train) #X_train normalised
X_train=np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=3)
X_test=np.expand_dims(X_test, axis=3)
X_train = X_train.astype('float32') / 255
X_test = X_test.astype('float32') / 255
X_train_mean = np.mean(X_train, axis=0)
X_train -= X_train_mean
X_test -= X_train_mean
print('x_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(X_test.shape[0], 'test samples')
xtrain=X_train[:3700]
ytrain=y_train[:3700]
#split data to train and test
xtest=X_train[3700:]
ytest=y_train[3700:]
t_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(ytrain, 3)
t_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(ytest, 3)
```

**Resnet Layer:**

```
def resnet_layer(inputs,
                 num_filters=16,#16
                 kernel_size=3,#3
                 strides=1,
                 activation='relu',
                 batch_normalization=True,
                 conv_first=True):
    
    conv = Conv2D(num_filters,
                  kernel_size=kernel_size,
                  strides=strides,
                  padding='same',
                  kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                  kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-4))

    x = inputs
    if conv_first:
        x = conv(x)
        if batch_normalization:
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
        if activation is not None:
            x = Activation(activation)(x)
    else:
        if batch_normalization:
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
        if activation is not None:
            x = Activation(activation)(x)
        x = conv(x)
    return x
```

**ResnetV1:**

```
def resnet_v1(input_shape, depth, num_classes=3):
  
    if (depth - 2) % 6 != 0:
        raise ValueError('depth should be 6n+2 (eg 20, 32, 44 in [a])')
    # Start model definition.
    num_filters = 16
    num_res_blocks = int((depth - 2) / 6)

    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = resnet_layer(inputs=inputs)
    # Instantiate the stack of residual units
    for stack in range(3):
        for res_block in range(num_res_blocks):
            strides = 1
            if stack > 0 and res_block == 0:  # first layer but not first stack
                strides = 2  # downsample
            y = resnet_layer(inputs=x,
                             num_filters=num_filters,
                             strides=strides)
            y = resnet_layer(inputs=y,
                             num_filters=num_filters,
                             activation=None)
            if stack > 0 and res_block == 0:  # first layer but not first stack
                # linear projection residual shortcut connection to match
                # changed dims
                x = resnet_layer(inputs=x,
                                 num_filters=num_filters,
                                 kernel_size=2, ### originally: 1,
                                 strides=strides,
                                 activation=None,
                                 batch_normalization=False)
            x = keras.layers.add([x, y])
            x = Activation('relu')(x)
        num_filters *= 2

    # Add classifier on top.
    # v1 does not use BN after last shortcut connection-ReLU

    x = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=8)(x)#8
    y = Flatten()(x)
    outputs = Dense(num_classes,
                    activation='softmax',            
                    kernel_initializer='he_normal')(y)          

    # Instantiate model.
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    print('Model parameters: {:d}'.format(model.count_params()))
    return model
```

**Learning rates:**

```
def lr_schedule(epoch):
    lr = 1e-3
    if epoch > 180:
        lr *= 0.5e-3
    elif epoch > 160:
        lr *= 1e-3
    elif epoch > 120:
        lr *= 1e-2
    elif epoch > 80:
        lr *= 1e-1
    return lr
```

**Compile:**

```
depth=50#50
input_shape = X_train.shape[1:]

model = resnet_v1(input_shape=input_shape, depth=depth)
    
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",# possible
              optimizer=Adam(lr=lr_schedule(0)),
              metrics=['acc'])
```

**Datagen,batch size,save model,ReduceLROnPlateau :**

```
batch_size =16#32  # orig paper trained all networks with batch_size=128 me 128 crusharei
epochs = 200

# Prepare model model saving directory.
model_name = 'resnet50F1-e{epoch:04d}-loss{loss:.3f}-acc{acc:.3f}-valloss{val_loss:.3f}-valacc{val_acc:.3f}.h5'
if not os.path.isdir(save_dir):
    os.makedirs(save_dir)
filepath = os.path.join(save_dir, model_name)

# Prepare callbacks for model saving and for learning rate adjustment.
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=filepath,
                             monitor='val_acc',
                             verbose=1,
                             save_best_only=True)

lr_scheduler = LearningRateScheduler(lr_schedule)

lr_reducer = ReduceLROnPlateau(factor=np.sqrt(0.1),
                               cooldown=0,
                               patience=5,
                               min_lr=0.5e-6)

# This will do preprocessing and realtime data augmentation:
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    # set input mean to 0 over the dataset
    featurewise_center=True,
    # set each sample mean to 0
    samplewise_center=True,
    # divide inputs by std of dataset
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,#true
    # divide each input by its std
    samplewise_std_normalization=True,
    # apply ZCA whitening
    zca_whitening=False, #true???
    # epsilon for ZCA whitening
    zca_epsilon=1e-06,#05?
    # randomly rotate images in the range (deg 0 to 180)
    rotation_range=0.,
    # randomly shift images horizontally
    width_shift_range=0.,#0.1
    # randomly shift images vertically
    height_shift_range=0.,#0.1
    # set range for random shear
    shear_range=0.,
    # set range for random zoom
    zoom_range=0., 
    # set range for random channel shifts
    channel_shift_range=0,
    # set mode for filling points outside the input boundaries
    fill_mode='nearest',
    # value used for fill_mode = "constant"
    cval=0.,
    # randomly flip images
    horizontal_flip=True,#True
    # randomly flip images
    vertical_flip=False,
    # set rescaling factor (applied before any other transformation)
    rescale=None,#none
    # set function that will be applied on each input
    preprocessing_function=None,
    # image data format, either "channels_first" or "channels_last"
    data_format=None,
    # fraction of images reserved for validation (strictly between 0 and 1)
    validation_split=0.0)

# Compute quantities required for featurewise normalization
# (std, mean, and principal components if ZCA whitening is applied).
datagen.fit(xtrain)
```

**Training:**

```
history = model.fit(datagen.flow(xtrain, t_train, batch_size=batch_size),
                               validation_data=(xtest, t_test),
                               epochs=epochs, verbose=0, workers=4,
                               steps_per_epoch = int(xtrain.shape[0]/batch_size),
                               callbacks=[lr_reducer, lr_scheduler, MyCallback(), checkpoint])


# Score trained model.
scores = model.evaluate(xtest, t_test, verbose=1)
print('Test loss:', scores[0])
print('Test accuracy:', scores[1])
```

Comment: For your learning rate, it appears you're implementing the decay yourself. The Adam optimizer does have a built in decay feature are you using a custom decay for a specific reason?
https://keras.io/api/optimizers/adam/

Comment: @Grizzle oh it was part of the original code that i have taken inspiration of i tried changing the value with very much the same results i will try optimizer's build in and will let you know

Comment: @couka it reduces after epoch 80 so yes it get smaller but the issue is already appearing by the epoch ~20 also decayed learing rate is helping on preveting it stuck as far as i know.

Comment: Nevermind, I was wrong with what I thought. The learning rate passed to Adam is constant `1e-3`, since you're always passing `0` as the epoch: `lr=lr_schedule(0)`, so that's fine, although unnecessarily complicated. Anyways, what's the class distribution of the dataset? Are you sure the network is learning anything at all, not just e.g. predicting the most frequent class always?

Comment: @couka i am not sure any tips on how to figure that one out?Also maybe add some answer so if you are correct i can give you the credits?

Comment: First you need to be able to properly interpret the accuracy figure, to judge what is happening. To do that, you need to know how frequent each class is. As an example: 50% accuracy in predicting a lottery is awesome. 50% accuracy in predicting a coin flip is nothing. I'll write a proper answer if and when we find a solution, I'm just poking around in the dark either.

Comment: @couka Also the dataset is of (1227 class 0),(2238 class 1), (1207 class 2)

Comment: It does appear the classes aren't evenly distributed, you could either discard some of the class 1 images or augment your other classes so the distribution is closer. There is a built in image augmenter in Keras (ImageDataGenerator). I believe augmenting would be the better option but it will mean increasing your dataset / training time.

Comment: @Grizzle thanks i will give it a shot after i try the build in decay from adam.

Comment: Image augmentation can be tried however, Keras imagedatagen does not increase the size of the dataset.

Comment: @Frightera not on disk, but it increases the number of unique samples that are available for training. So in that sense it does increase the size of the dataset. On topic: Always predicting class 1 on that dataset would result in an accuracy of 47.9% and I'd guess that is what's happening.

Comment: @Grizzle i tested the default learning rate with some very interesting case now acc and validation acc are at the same level about 46~49% next step is try to change the imbalance of data.I am starting to think that the model actually preditcs the same class over and over any tips on how to configure/debug it?

Comment: @couka it seems like a valid option i will try to make the dataset even but any way to make sure that the model actually predicts the same class?

Comment: Yes, look at the predictions :D Just like `model.evaluate()` provides you with metrics (like Accuracy), `model.predict()` will get you the actual predictions.

Comment: how are labels encoded, one-hot or integers ? Also have you tried without any augmentation ?

Comment: @couka, yes he is using augmentation in the `datagen` like random horizontal flip. If you are looking at pictures of lung as is this case, you are basically swapping the right and left lung randomly. It might have an impact on the model if the spatial localisation of each lung is essential in identifying the right class.

Comment: @YoanB.M.Sc at first getting them from csv file as integers and then transform them to categorical(one-hot) for instance : if image with class 2 the matrix will be [0,0,1] so it can be fed to softmax.

Comment: @YoanB.M.Sc without augmentation i get results of (acc up to 99%,validation acc 46-49%)which is weird because adding augmentation doesnt seem to affect validation acc thats why i though that it might not be typical overfitting

Comment: @couka ok i might need up to 2 hours to execute your suggestion so sit back and relax i guess.

Comment: @HelloMyNameIsDennis, it's because you should not apply data augmentation to your validation. The purpose of validation is to assess accuracy on "unspoiled" data. Augmentation is just used on the training set to generate more data while (hopefully) preserving the features of interest.

Comment: @YoanB.M.Sc sorry but at which point am i augmenting validation?i think that i am only augmenting training set can you be more spesific.

Comment: @HelloMyNameIsDennis, my mistake, I misread your comment. Given the size of your data have you tried first with a simple model ? MLP, or CNN with just one or 2 layers. You won't break accuracy record but if even simple model without any augmentation still yield the same results it can  give us a hint

Comment: @YoanB.M.Sc well i tried but was not able to because i am still learning. i tried resnet with 8 depth with similar results but your suggestion has a valid point sorry i am not able to perfom it

Comment: @HelloMyNameIsDennis, no problem we are all learning :). If I can share one advice, try implementing simple model you understand first. Jumping to advance architecture without understanding would probably waste you a lot of time, plus there is no evidence that you would get much better results. Good luck !

Comment: @couka i tried predicting i get this result  [0.253 0.475 0.273]  as of all the outputs i guess that is what you said about predicting the same class every time now do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I agree, that's excellent advise. What's the output on training data? If a model resorts to predicting constant values, it usually does that on train data too. So I wonder how it can achieve high train accuracy. I suspect there's something wrong with the training data (or how you feed it) itself. Maybe manually inspect what the training data looks like after preprocessing.

Comment: @YoanB.M.Sc well thanks but i would really like to build resnet and then as a next step a mixture of experts (resnets) as i would like to make an assignment about the benefits of mixtures of experts as far as this model goes do you have any suggestion or shall i close this thread?

Comment: You can always drop a resnet architecture back into your code, after you get it to work with a simple model. It's not helpful to insist on using a large model if the code around it is flawed. That just makes training and therefore debugging slower.